# Why are parentheses (or braces) needed in this minimal Makefile?

Tags: bash, variables, makefile, variable-expansion

I am baffled why I need to echo `$(VAR1)` or `${VAR1}` to get the output "abcd" in this Makefile:

```
VAR1=abcd

myTarget:
        @echo $VAR1

all: myTarget

.PHONY: all
```

Instead, make will echo `$V` (which is the empty string), and then "AR1", which is my output.

I know in `bash`, `echo $VAR1` works to get "abcd", and my understanding is that the indented part of the code is run in `bash`.  I'm using GNU Make 3.81.

Answer (score 1):

It's needed because that's the syntax make uses to reference variables.  For instance see the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html), or even the POSIX standard definition of `make`.

Note that makefiles are *not* shell scripts, and don't have the same syntax as shell scripts.  Makefiles do *contain* shell scripts (or at least shell commands), in recipes.

By setting the variable:

```
VAR1 = abcd
```

in your makefile you're creating a *make* variable, not a *shell* variable.

A recipe (command indented by a TAB) is first parsed by make and all the make variable references are expanded.  Then the result of that expansion is passed to the shell.  Since you want to refer to a *make* variable in your recipe, you have to use the make variable reference syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> I know in `bash`, `echo $VAR1` works to get "abcd", and my understanding is that the indented part of the code is what is executed by `bash`.

`$VAR1` is expanded by `make` (not `bash`), and it is actually equivalent to expanding `$(V)AR1`. The resulting line after that expansion is what is executed by `bash`.

You need to escape the leading `$` in `$VAR1` to prevent `make` from expanding the variable. The escaping can be achieved by placing an additional `$` before `$VAR1`, i.e.:

```
myTarget:
        @echo $$VAR1
```

This way, `bash` will receive the line `echo $VAR1`.